Amazon Linux2に、NVIDIA driver version 525.89.02をインストールしたい
環境
Amazon Linux2

インスタンスタイプ
g4dn.2xlarge

gccのversion
[ec2-user@ip ~]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-17)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[ec2-user@ip ~]$ rpm -q gcc
gcc-7.3.1-17.amzn2.x86_64

kernelのversion
[ec2-user@ip ~]$ uname -r
5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64

[ec2-user@ip ~]$ rpm -q kernel-devel
kernel-devel-5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64

やりたいこと
Amazon Linux2に、NVIDIA driver version 525.89.02をインストールしたい。
実施したこと
参考サイト：https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-nvidia-driver.html#nvidia-gaming-driver
sudo yum install gcc make
sudo yum update -y
sudo reboot
sudo yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools"
sudo yum install -y kernel-devel-$(uname -r) kernel-headers-$(uname -r)

sudo aws s3 cp s3://nvidia-gaming/linux/525.89.02-Feb2023-Cloud_Gaming-Linux-Guest-Drivers.zip .

sudo unzip 525.89.02-Feb2023-Cloud_Gaming-Linux-Guest-Drivers.zip -d nvidia-drivers

sudo chmod +x nvidia-drivers/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64*-grid.run

sudo CC=/usr/bin/gcc10-cc ./nvidia-drivers/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64*.run

結果

エラーログ
/var/log/nvidia-installer.logの851行目~903行目を抜粋します。
FATAL: modpost: GPL-incompatible module nvidia.ko uses GPL-only symbol 'rcu_read_unlock_strict'
make[5]: *** [/tmp/selfgz21584/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.89.02-grid/kernel/Module.symvers] Error 1
make[5]: Target `__modpost' not remade because of errors.
make[4]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[3]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[2]: *** [__sub-make] Error 2
make[2]: Target `modules' not remade because of errors.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64'
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
-> Checking to see whether the nvidia kernel module was successfully built
   executing: 'cd ./kernel; /bin/make -k -j8  NV_EXCLUDE_KERNEL_MODULES="" SYSSRC="/lib/modules/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64/source" SYSOUT="/lib/modules/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64/build" NV_KERNEL_MODULES="nvidia"'...
   make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64'
   /bin/make -f Makefile.kernel CROSS_COMPILE="gcc10-" CC="/usr/bin/gcc10-cc" HOSTCC="gcc10-gcc" HOSTCXX="gcc10-g++" LD="ld" modules
   make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64'
   /bin/make -f Makefile.kernel CROSS_COMPILE="gcc10-" CC="/usr/bin/gcc10-cc" HOSTCC="gcc10-gcc" HOSTCXX="gcc10-g++" LD="ld" modules
   scripts/Makefile.lib:8: 'always' is deprecated. Please use 'always-y' instead
     MODPOST /tmp/selfgz21584/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.89.02-grid/kernel/Module.symvers
   FATAL: modpost: GPL-incompatible module nvidia.ko uses GPL-only symbol 'rcu_read_unlock_strict'
   make[5]: *** [/tmp/selfgz21584/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.89.02-grid/kernel/Module.symvers] Error 1
   make[5]: Target `__modpost' not remade because of errors.
   make[4]: *** [modules] Error 2
   make[3]: *** [modules] Error 2
   make[2]: *** [__sub-make] Error 2
   make[2]: Target `modules' not remade because of errors.
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64'
   make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
   make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64'
   make: *** [modules] Error 2
-> Error.
ERROR: An error occurred while performing the step: "Checking to see whether the nvidia kernel module was successfully built". See /var/log/nvidia-installer.log for details.
-> The command `cd ./kernel; /bin/make -k -j8  NV_EXCLUDE_KERNEL_MODULES="" SYSSRC="/lib/modules/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64/source" SYSOUT="/lib/modules/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64/build" NV_KERNEL_MODULES="nvidia"` failed with the following output:

make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64'
/bin/make -f Makefile.kernel CROSS_COMPILE="gcc10-" CC="/usr/bin/gcc10-cc" HOSTCC="gcc10-gcc" HOSTCXX="gcc10-g++" LD="ld" modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64'
/bin/make -f Makefile.kernel CROSS_COMPILE="gcc10-" CC="/usr/bin/gcc10-cc" HOSTCC="gcc10-gcc" HOSTCXX="gcc10-g++" LD="ld" modules
scripts/Makefile.lib:8: 'always' is deprecated. Please use 'always-y' instead
  MODPOST /tmp/selfgz21584/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.89.02-grid/kernel/Module.symvers
FATAL: modpost: GPL-incompatible module nvidia.ko uses GPL-only symbol 'rcu_read_unlock_strict'
make[5]: *** [/tmp/selfgz21584/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.89.02-grid/kernel/Module.symvers] Error 1
make[5]: Target `__modpost' not remade because of errors.
make[4]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[3]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[2]: *** [__sub-make] Error 2
make[2]: Target `modules' not remade because of errors.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64'
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/5.10.228-219.884.amzn2.x86_64'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
ERROR: The nvidia kernel module was not created.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.

解決案について
GCCとKernelのversionが原因だと睨んでいます。
どのように対策すればよいでしょうか？

バージョンは525.89.02に限られ、他のバージョンではいけないのでしょうか？ またバージョン確認はgcc --versionなのになぜそれとは違うCC=/usr/bin/gcc10-ccを指定しているのでしょうか？

Amazon ECS に最適化された Linux AMIというものがあります。

Amazon Linux 2
Kernel 5.10
NVIDIA driver 550

がインストールされているので、NVIDIA driverバージョンにこだわりがなければ、イメージ名に
resolve:ssm:/aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/kernel-5.10/gpu/recommended/image_id

を指定するだけで利用できます。
バージョン525にこだわる必要があるなら、AWSがAmazon ECS に最適化された Linux AMIをどのように作成しているか、aws/amazon-ecs-amiから手順を確認できます。具体的には/scripts/enable-ecs-agent-gpu-support.shがインストールを行っています。
概要としては
[amzn2-nvidia]
name=Amazon Linux 2 Nvidia repository
mirrorlist=$awsproto://$amazonlinux.$awsregion.$awsdomain/$releasever/amzn2-nvidia/latest/$basearch/mirror.list
priority=20
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/rhel7/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
enabled=1
exclude=libglvnd-*

というリポジトリを追加して、nvidia-driver-latest-dkms-525.89.02をインストールする形でしょうか。該当バージョンが置かれていなかったらごめんなさい。
他にもいろいろやっているので、必要な処理を行ってください。
